# Как исправить баг в LibreOffice 6.2.3.2 на Windows 7 (иных не уточнено), где буффер обмена внешний "отваливается"?

Tags: libre-office

Бага ПостСледствия

1. Это заставляет делать постоянно Control+C, Control+V (итераций 3), пока возможность вставлять из буффера обмена внешнего, не возвращаетюся

Бага уточнения

1. Не помогало переустанавливать
2. Не помогало на долго, программу перезагружать.
3. В OpenOffice открытом параллельно, ситуация такая не вознмала (если предположить, что это плохо сделанная передпоиска на Windows API, в случае если Windows API события буффера "вручать" перестаёт (handle).

Comment: Ната проста сбить soffice.bin из Ctrl+Shift+Esc и тут же стартануть офис пановай - до пирезагрузки системы буффер бутет работать нормаль

Comment: soffiece.exe было бесполезно сбивать
На его месте, на тот же файл, был запущен даже OpenOffice (предок LibreOffice), и он имел баг тот же самый (что он видит буффер обмена, не так как программы все остальные (то есть видит свой буффер))

Comment: а если завершить прям soffice.bin, то завершится и soffice.exe, и ба никуда не денется (может на минут 10 пропадёт, по алгоритмам не ясным). И вообще у OfficeLibre исходников компиляцию никто не проверял видимо, чтобы что-то там поменять.